# Parallel Reduction

Tags: c++, c, cuda, parallel-processing, gpu

I have read the article Optimizing Parallel Reduction in CUDA by Mark Harris, and I found it really very useful, but still I am sometimes unable to understand 1 or 2 concepts.
It is written on pg 18:

```
//First add during load

// each thread loads one element from global to shared mem

unsigned int tid = threadIdx.x;

unsigned int i = blockIdx.x*blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;

sdata[tid] = g_idata[i];
__syncthreads();
```

Optimized Code: With 2 loads and 1st add of the reduction:

```
// perform first level of reduction,

// reading from global memory, writing to shared memory
unsigned int tid = threadIdx.x;                                    ...1

unsigned int i = blockIdx.x*(blockDim.x*2) + threadIdx.x;          ...2

sdata[tid] = g_idata[i] + g_idata[i+blockDim.x];                   ...3

__syncthreads();                                                   ...4
```

I am unable to understand line 2; if I have 256 elements, and if I choose 128 as my blocksize, then why I am multiplying it with 2? Please explain how to determine the blocksize?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Basically, it is performing the operation shown in the picture below:

[image]

This code is basically *saying* that half of the threads will performance the reading from global memory and writing to shared memory, as shown in the picture.

You execute a Kernel, and now you want to reduce some values, you limit the access to the code above to only half of the total of threads running. Imagining you have 4 blocks, each one with 512 threads, you limit the code above to only be executed by the first two blocks, and you have a `g_idate[4*512]`:

```
unsigned int i = blockIdx.x*(blockDim.x*2) + threadIdx.x;  

sdata[tid] = g_idata[i] + g_idata[i+blockDim.x];
```

So:

```
thread 0 of block = 0  will copy the position 0 and 512,  
thread 1 of block = 0 position 1 and 513;
thread 511 of block = 0 position 511 and 1023;
thread 0 of block 1 position 1024 and 1536
thread 511 of block = 1 position 1535 and 2047
```

The `blockDim.x*2` is used because each thread will access to position `i` and `i+blockDim.x` so you need to multiple by `2` to guarantee that the threads on next `id` block do not compute the position of `g_idata` already computed.

Answer (score 1):

In the optimized code you run the kernel with blocks half as large as in the non-optimized implementation.

Let's call the size of the block in non-optimized code `work`, let half of this size be called `unit`, and let these sizes have same numerical value for the optimized code as well.

In the non-optimized code you run the kernel with as many threads as the `work` is, that is `blockDim = 2 * unit`. The code in each block just copies part of `g_idata` to an array in shared memory, of size `2 * unit`.

In the optimized code `blockDim = unit`, so there are now 1/2 of the threads, and the array in shared memory is 2x smaller. In line 3 first summand comes from even units, while second from odd units. In this way all the data required for reduction is taken into account.

Example:
If you run non-optimized kernel with `blockDim=256=work` (single block, `unit=128`), then optimized code has a single block of `blockDim=128=unit`. Since this block gets `blockIdx=0`, the `*2` does not matter; the first thread does `g_idata[0] + g_idata[0 + 128]`.

If you had 512 elements, and run non-optimized with 2 blocks of size 256 (`work=256`, `unit=128`), then optimized code has 2 blocks, but now of size 128. The first thread in second block (`blockIdx=1`) does `g_idata[2*128] + g_idata[2*128+128]`.

Comment: @P Marecki   : Thank you very much. Your answer really helps me understanding the solution, but if you can let me know that in first paragraph, what is the total elements. If it is 256, then how 256 elements would be occupied by single block? Same question for 2nd paragraph 512 elements and only 2 blocks with 128 threads.

Comment: @robot : Total number of elements in `g_idata` is 256 in 1st paragraph, and 512 in second. True: in optimized code `sdata` is `2x` smaller (you only have `128` elements there, or `2 * 128` in 2nd paragraph), but this is enough for the purpose of reduction.

Comment: @P Marecki   : Thanks for your reply. But if there are 256 elements then we have to process 256 elements, how elements are reduced to 128 elements? You mean there are 256 elements, and we are having 1 block with block size of 128 for processing 256 elements?

Comment: @P Marecki: Should not it be that: number of blocks should be halved in optimized code as compared tonon-optimized code. You have written that for 512 elements, initially there were blocks with 256 threads/block and in optimized code there are 128 threads/block; then where we are halving the number of blocks?

Comment: @robot : I think I understood the source of confusion. In the edited answer there are now variables `work` and `unit`, which have same numerical values for both implementations, while `blockDim` is different in both.

Comment: @P Marecki     : Actually it is written "Halve the number of blocks", and it is not written "Halve the block size". Then should not it to be reduced from 2 blocks to 1 block withe 256 threads/block for processing 512 elements?

Comment: @robot : This is equivalent. Once you see the reduction is correctly done with halved blocks, you are of course free to rescale the sizes of the blocks as you wish; doubling the size of blocks halves their number.

Comment: @P Marecki     :Ok thanks for your reply. I will work over it; also if possible I will check with number of blocks and number of threads.